# Asynchronously populate/pre-fill multiple, user mutable `@State` values when using SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, combine

I have some `TextField(s)` with “.text” values that are supposed to be populated by a method called within “**init()**” (can be moved) that asynchronously calls a completion handler with a `struct` of data from the network.

The thing is... the user can also **begin typing into them manually** in the meantime and the completion callback **shouldn’t overwrite the manually edited values**.

I’m not sure how to:

1. Update the values of the `@State String` variables to replace the existing values only if they haven’t been modified by the user yet... while **also** having them be mutable by the end-user.
2. Update N number of the `@State` values from the same request at once. One request is used to pull **all** of the data in, so mapping into a single value while having it be mutable as noted above is a head scratcher at the moment.

It seems like a job for Combine, just not sure where to start yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the user-edit is per-field and all other fields should be left alone.

Move all state inside an `ObservableObject`, make the state variables *@Published*, take a publisher from each and create a sink from each setting a variable `if stateX != initialStateXValue { stateXUserModified = true }` inside each sink and have a method *networkUpdate(loadedData:)* on the *ObservableObject* which only sets the state if the associated *stateXUserModified* is false.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! Although it kind of sucks to have a single “mutable state” object with these things in it.

Comment: If for example, I wanted to also show an **`Alert`** if there was an error, I’d have to move the single `Identifiable` **var** for the entire `View` into that as well, wouldn’t I?

Comment: Ex. `.alert($interactiveState.alertPresentable) { (presentable) -> Alert in /* ... */ }` since it seems like only the first `.alert` in each `View` is supported, at least in Xcode 11b5?

Comment: You can put the whole thing into a property wrapper too which makes it much better to use and reuse.

Comment: I don't see the connection between presenting errors and the question (modifying state based on whether It was user-modified or not). I heard it's possible to show multiple `.sheet` by using `Text("").hidden().alert`, but that is another question